# How to center an equation at the center of one column in a two-column paper

Tags: equations, two-column

In a `two columns` paper, how can I center an equation to the center of one column?
Originally, what I have is:

```
\begin{equation}
y = ax
\end{equation}
```

But this fits the equation to stay, as normal text, at the left side of the column.

EDIT: I think, better than the MWE, is the link to [this class](ftp://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/readme.html), which I am using.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem. Furthermore the answer may depend on the packages that you are using.

Comment: Can't reproduce your claim with a two-column article class. So a suitable MWE would help greatly.

Comment: You should test, if this problem exists only with your special class. And we still need an MWE. We do not like external links without even knowing if we have to download something. In case, an MWE with `\documentclass{article}` works as well, it would save as a lot of time.

Comment: equation centres by default but many classes have a `fleqn` option to set equations flush left, sounds like that is in operation in your case.

Answer (score 4):

The class uses

```
\LoadClass[fleqn]{article}
```

to specify flush left equations, with no documented way of over-riding that.

that is really the point of publisher specific classes, to remove flexibility to enforce a house style.

Comment: Thanks! You mean: the class is built to avoid centred equations?

Comment: @Py-ser yes `fleqn`is for flush left, ie not centred equations.